# Merge same named arrays in ruby hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.2

I'd like to take two hashes of a form like these:

```
hash_1 = {:a=>{:b=>3, :c=>{:stuff1=>[{:d=>1, :e=>2}, {:d=>4, :e=>2}], :stuff2=>[{:f=>33, :g=>44}, {:f=>55, :g=>66}], :h=>4}}}

hash_2 = {:a=>{:b=>3, :c=>{:stuff1=>[{:d=>8, :e=>5}, {:d=>7, :e=>5}], :stuff2=>[{:f=>45, :g=>89}, {:f=>78, :g=>67}], :h=>4}}}
```

And get this back (note `:stuff1` and `:stuff2` are added together):

```
result = {:a=>{:b=>3, :c=>{:stuff1=>[{:d=>1, :e=>2}, {:d=>4, :e=>2}, {:d=>8, :e=>5}, {:d=>7, :e=>5}], :stuff2=>[{:f=>33, :g=>44}, {:f=>55, :g=>66}, {:f=>45, :g=>89}, {:f=>78, :g=>67}], :h=>4}}}
```

I've found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413481/ruby-merge-hashes-putting-keys-into-csv-string), but my case is with nested hashes, so any help from some good ruby hands would be appreciated.

Basically, I want to "merge" the array values of same named keys *when* the values corresponding to those keys are *arrays*.  Of course the following will **replace** `hash_1`'s `:stuff1` array with `hash_2`'s `:stuff1` array (and similarly for `:stuff2`), but I want an array '`+`' type of merge, not an update/replace, or merge! ...

```
hash_1.merge(hash_2)  # NOT what I want => {:a=>{:b=>3, :c=>{:stuff1=>[{:d=>8, :e=>5}, {:d=>7, :e=>5}], :stuff2=>[{:f=>45, :g=>89}, {:f=>78, :g=>67}], :h=>4}}}
```

I'm using ruby 1.9.2, btw.  I know hashes have been updated a bit lately, though I don't think that'll affect the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: what if `hash_1 = {:a=>{:b=>3 ..` and `hash_1 = {:a=>{:b=>4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# adapted from http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4706
class Hash
  def deep_merge_with_array_values_concatenated(hash)
    target = dup

    hash.keys.each do |key|
      if hash[key].is_a? Hash and self[key].is_a? Hash
        target[key] = target[key].deep_merge_with_array_values_concatenated(hash[key])
        next
      end

      if hash[key].is_a?(Array) && target[key].is_a?(Array)
        target[key] = target[key] + hash[key]
      else
        target[key] = hash[key]
      end
    end

    target
  end
end

p hash_1.deep_merge_with_array_values_concatenated(hash_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define block for merge method, this block will be called for each duplication key.

```
hash_1.merge(hash_2) do |key, old_value, new_value|
  old_value + new_value
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the specifications are not complete. Anyway, a functional recursive approach (second hash only used to concat values on array values):

```
class Hash
  def concat_on_common_array_values(hash)
    Hash[map do |key, value|
      if value.is_a?(Hash) && hash[key].is_a?(Hash)
        [key, value.concat_on_common_array_values(hash[key])] 
      elsif value.is_a?(Array) && hash[key].is_a?(Array)
        [key, value + hash[key]]
      else
        [key, value]
      end      
    end]
  end
end

p hash_1.concat_on_common_array_values(hash_2)
# {:a=>{:b=>3, :c=>{:stuff1=>[{:d=>1, :e=>2}, {:d=>4, :e=>2}, {:d=>8, :e=>5}, {:d=>7, :e=>5}], :stuff2=>[{:f=>33, :g=>44}, {:f=>55, :g=>66}, {:f=>45, :g=>89}, {:f=>78, :g=>67}], :h=>4}}}
```